# Bug while adding numbers google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

The calculation in cell I15 should result in 0 but instead it is 0,0000000000000000004336808....

Any idea why this happens?

The calculation is pretty simple, just 0,00125574 - 0,00125574

Below is the sheet that I'm referring to:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cDKTIUfN8r6IGZqnSd-yjRBQxkdiMRJX4fQZAyLZpmY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It's floating point error mitigation. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41859616/funny-rounding-errors-when-adding)

Comment: Sure, this helps. I knew that it was a floating-point error, but I didn't expect it to happen for such calculations.