# Google sheets: zero is not zero

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I have a column of numbers. There is a difference between the result of the formula SUM() and the number entered from the keyboard. I can't find the reason why the result of the subtraction is not zero. Here is the link to the sheet:
[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MG2Zb3TGb1afmWPqpEDrIAwyGDDXjVrlvUgINcuXE_4/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Similar to this as well. [Funny (rounding?) errors when adding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41859616/funny-rounding-errors-when-adding)

Comment: Yes, I think that is it... Thank you.